# How to "reset" iteration through an Enumeration list

Tags: java, enumeration

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets
        = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

out.print("List of all network interfaces on this machine:\n");

for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets)) {
    out.printf("name:%s (%s)\n", netint.getName(), netint.getDisplayName());
}
```

I'm doing an assignment that requires me to list a bunch of information using NetworkInterface, but I'm not very familiar with Enumeration, so I'm having trouble.

I went through some javadocs and managed to get this far. The problem is that I need to be able to go through the list multiple times.

For example, I was wanting to use another for loop to cycle through and list all interfaces that were currently up.

Something like this:

```
for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets)) {
    if (netint.isUp()) {
       out.printf("name:%s (%s)\n", netint.getName(), netint.getDisplayName());
    }
}
```

However, any time I use a for loop after the first one I'm not getting any output. I have a feeling this has to do with my lack of understanding. I can't seem to find an explanation anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enumeration can't be reset. The reason your code doesn't work is because your first call to `Collections.list(nets)` "depleats" the `nets` enumeration, so the next call to `Collections.list(nets)` yields an empty collection.

To avoid this collect the interfaces from the `nets` enumeration and iterate over the resulting list instead:

```
List<NetworkInteface> list = Collections.list(nets);

// Iteration 1
for (NetworkInterface netint : list) {
    ...
}

// Iteration 2
for (NetworkInterface netint : list) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. I guess I should read more about lists as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either:

- call `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` afresh before every loop (so that you get a new `Enumeration` object); or
- store the results of `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` in a list *once*, and then just iterate over that list.

To illustrate the second approach:

```
List<NetworkInterface> nets = Collections.list(
                                 NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());

for (NetworkInterface netint : nets) {
   ...
}

for (NetworkInterface netint : nets) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Iterator instead of Enumeration.
Refer this docs,
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Comment: a) You can't get an iterator from the `NetworkInterface` class. b) you can't reset an iterator either!